# Trigger an action whenever a mail is received using Java

Tags: java, email, smtp, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES to send notification emails to users. SMTP properties like username, host and password are customizable and I am storing it in a properties file. 
I want to trigger an action whenever a user replies to these emails. Is there a way I can do this?
Currently I am having a scheduled a quartz job which keeps checking if any new emails are there in every minute. It looks like an overload. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store incoming replies to S3 and then have S3 Put event cause an AWS lambda invocation.

For more details on this click [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/receiving-email-with-amazon-ses/) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html)

Now from your AWS Lambda you can trigger your user action.

For more details on S3 triggering Lambda click [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)

This way you do not need to poll continuously and will be much cheaper as well

Comment: Can you help me with a resource I can follow to get this done?

Comment: Thanks for the links. Is it possible to add Lambda Function into my existing Java Project itself ? Or do I need to create a separate Lambda Project as they say

Comment: You can add the Lambda Function to tour existing Java project. But it is always good to keep them seperate

Comment: I was trying to set up forward email from outlook to SES can u help me with this @Arafat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181230/how-to-make-outlook-forward-email-to-aws-ses